# Compare Variable to each child element text

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to cycle through a list of usernames and grant permissions based on the userid passed in. Im going to provide the code and ask my questions at the end, I think it will make it easier.

```
    MY XML
    <QueueSelector>
    <DB></DB>
    <FillQuery></FillQuery>
    <TabText></TabText>
    <TooltipText></TooltipText>
    <Subscribers>
      <WorkSpace>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
        <Name></Name>
  </QueueSelector>
```

Each Name Element obviously contains a username. My goal is to pass in a variable and test it against the text of each name. Currently I am doing..

```
   CAST(info.query('/Root/QueueSelector/Subscribers/WorkSpace/Name/text()') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%' + @UserID + '%'
```

This returns a long string. The problem is A person with username asmith would have access if a person casmith has access.

I guess my question is what would be the best way to solve this problem. Im familar with doing

```
    info.query('/Root/QueueSelector/Subscribers/WorkSpace/Name[1]/text())
```

however I do not know which element would contain the persons username, if it even exists.

I know I asked this question horribly, anything i can clarify let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [exist() Method (xml Data Type)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) and [sql:variable() Function (XQuery)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx).

```
info.exist('/Root/QueueSelector/Subscribers/WorkSpace/Name[. = sql:variable("@UserID")]') = 1
```

Comment: i dont quite understand your answer. by exist i mean does the username exist in one of the name elements

Comment: Yes. The exist function returns a 1 if the username is in one of the name elements.